"Must specify at least one OAuthAuthenticationModes" in Git clone of material for Go-CD
I see this information for my material failing to clone in Go-CD:
    [go] Start to update materials.

    [go] Start updating files at revision d6cdbe2ec2bb329ca97aa462be02bd684fd527c3 from https://[companyWebSite.com/MyFolder/MyRepo].git
    STDERR: Cloning into 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Go Agent\pipelines\[PipelineName]'...
    STDERR: fatal: Must specify at least one OAuthAuthenticationModes
    STDERR: Parameter name: modes
    STDERR: bash: line 1: /dev/tty: No such device or address
    STDERR: error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
    STDERR: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://companyWebSite.com': No such file or directory

I have no login information provided for the material, though I have provided the branch. The Test Connection button indicates Connection OK.
Googling, I find no references anywhere to OAuthAuthenticationModes and have no idea what it could be referring to, or how to configure it.
I did add C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin to the system path, which has SSH.exe in it, as advised elsewhere, but I'm not clear on SSH, and anyway it seemed not to help.
I have a suspicion that it has something to do with a different AD user on the Go Server than the Go Agent uses, but can't figure out a way to see if this is true, or to set up a different user for the material.
Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this so the material will clone properly?
UPDATE: As mentioned, though it can work without Git login information provided for the material, providing the login information produces something different. The same STDERR first line, but then it seems to HANG without making additional progress. It creates my [PipelineName] folder, but only puts files in the hidden .git folder.

Though it LOOKS OK to leave the user name and password for the material for Git blank, it turns out filling this in with valid credentials seems to work. STDERR seems to be nothing more than indicating the start of a logging message, and doesn't represent an actual error, but the output.
The "hanging" part seems to have simply been the material taking a long time, almost a half hour, to pull the repository. That is just the first time; subsequent times were only measured in seconds.
